# About the optimization of query statements in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql

```
select p1.* from history p1, history p2   
where p1.charge   =   p2.charge  
and   p1.userkey   =   p2.userkey   
and   p1.invitekey   =   p2.invitekey
and   p1.aid!=p2.aid
```

If there're lots of datas, it will be so slow, so how can I optimize this?

Comment: Use modern join syntax, and then add indices to the columns in the `ON` clause, if they would benefit from that.

Comment: try using join properly... It will help you better... use join as per your table...

Answer (score 0):

you can add indexes to the columns you are using in where clause, This will increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what indexes already exist on those tables.
So you should check that, and then think about wether an extra should be added to avoid full table scans.

But as a start, it's better to use [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) syntax.
It's more readable because the join criteria are separated from the search criteria.

```
select h1.*, h2.aid as h2_aid
from history h1
join history h2
  on (h2.charge = h1.charge and h2.userkey = h1.userkey and h2.invitekey = h1.invitekey)
where h1.aid != h2.aid
```

But in your case you only select those from p1.
So I assume that an [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) could be used instead.

```
select *
from history h1
where exists
(
   select *
   from history h2
   where h2.charge = h1.charge 
     and h2.userkey = h1.userkey 
     and h2.invitekey = h1.invitekey
     and h2.aid != h1.aid
)
```

Comment: I tried join and exist, but still slowly, but thank you all the same.

Comment: @matt Based on the field names, I have a hunch that a non-unique index on `userkey` could help.  There's probably already an index on `aid`, but that won't be used because of the `!=`.